# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oauth:authorization-server'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring security oAuth2 here is my `spring-security.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd ">
```

`pom.xml`

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <context.path>mobapp</context.path>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>    
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If my system is connected to internet it works fine else show this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 117 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 117; columnNumber: 51; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'oauth:authorization-server'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are getting is due to the fact that the `xsd` schemas loaded from the jar files on your classpath are missing the stated element.

In my view a good practice is to ommit the version numbers from the headers e.g.
`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd`

instead of

`xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd`.

This way you ensure that the xml is verified against the schema's from the file, because the schema's are packaged inside the jars with the version number stripped. Otherwise, the schema is loaded from the Internet, and if there's a mistmatch, you don't see it in compile time.

This being said, you seem to include the older version of the `oauth` dependency, try with e.g.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```